# How to remove in bootstrap active class from nav on index page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for menu in header. And on default, first link is active(li have class 'active') on index.php, but I want to make no active link on index.php.

[image: active li on index page]

How to disable active li only on index page, may be change bootstrap.js or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further input from you, you can simply remove the class by editing out the `HTML`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, that problem is not in bootstrap. The problem in widget from framework YII2, which generate nav. The question is incorrect.

Comment: so, is there anything else?